# What is the "testCasePathName" in TestLink?

Tags: java, import, testcase, testlink

I am trying to import test case results in TestLink. To do that, I have to use the method : api.getTestCaseIDByName(testCaseName, testSuiteName, projectName, testCasePathName) from the TestLinkAPI library.

The problem is I can't find out what "testCasePathName" corresponds to ...
Do you have any idea ?
It would be very helpful ! Thank you

Comment: Link to the library?

Answer (score 2):

Finally managed to find out what was the testCasePathName.
It is a String with this format : "[projectName]::[testSuiteName]::[testCaseName]" where :
- projectName is the name of your project in TestLink,
- testSuiteName is the name of your TestSuite int TestLink
- testCaseName is the name of your testCase in TestLink

Hope it will help someone someday ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the library you're speaking about is [this one](https://github.com/kinow/testlink-java-api/blob/342242e01635a6f0d9e717aa2cea5ea21d38aa3b/src/main/java/br/eti/kinoshita/testlinkjavaapi/TestLinkAPI.java)...

```
public Integer getTestCaseIDByName(String testCaseName, String testSuiteName, String testProjectName,
        String testCasePathName) throws TestLinkAPIException {
    return this.testCaseService.getTestCaseIDByName(testCaseName, testSuiteName, testProjectName, testCasePathName);
}
```

The program is going to expect a pile of `String`s as the types for your parameters. You'll have to provide the names of the elements which are named. You may also want to look at the method which is referenced in the return statement to get a better understanding of how the matching system works in this library.

Comment: Yes this is the one I am talking about and it is exactly this function I am using. But even after looking at documentation, I have trouble to find what is the "testCasePathName"

Comment: The library does have JavaDocs. If possible, download them so you can view them in your IDE. If you use Maven, that's quite simple (for Eclipse, right click, `Maven > Download JavaDocs`). Otherwise, you can read the docs based off the source in the GitHub repository. If the answer is helpful, feel free to accept.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but if you looked at the javadocs, you probably notified there were none information about what we exactly have to put in the "testClassPathName" field